# How can i create a window with application scope in zkoss.?

Tags: java, zk

In my zkoss application , i have a main parent window having an iframe child. In the iframe there is another window in which a modal window is populating on clicking a button. but that modal window disabling only the second window. not the main window.how can i make it disable fully on click the button..?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Executions.createComponent(...)`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/6.5.1/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Executions.html#createComponents%28java.lang.String,%20org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component,%20java.util.Map%29) instead of iFrame,
so everything will be on the same Desktop and the modal window
will disable everything.
Reading [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ZUML/Load_ZUML_in_Java) should help too.